# Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 and Tracking

Tags: windows, tracking, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working with the Beta 2 Version of Visual Studio 2010 to get some advanced learning of how to use WF4.  I'm using code similar to that in the SqlTracking sample from the SDK, and am trying to track complex objects, of types that I have created, that I have passed into the workflow as arguments.  In the CustomerTrackingEventsTable in the tracking database there is a field named SerializedData of type NVarChar(Max).  My tracking records are getting stored there, in what appears to be XML.  I've been unable to figure out how to use this data in a consuming application because I am unable to open it in code as an XML file, nor can I open it with the XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer.  Any ideas on how to use this type of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an enumerated type that the class I was trying to track was using, and I needed to add the [DataContract] attribute to the enum itself, and the [EnumMember] attribute to the item within the enum.